# Laravel Checkbox not getting set correctly

Tags: laravel, checkbox

Given the following code, all my checkboxes (roles) are marked as checked, even though the user only has one role.

Using Laravel and Spatie Laravel Permissions Package.

I tried the same code in Tinker and it comes back with True, False, False, so it should be working...

```
@foreach ($roles as $role)
    <div>
        <label>
            <input type="checkbox" value="{{ $role->name }}" checked="{{ $user->hasRole($role->name) ? 'checked' : '' }}">
            <span>
                {{ $role->name }}
            </span>
        </label>
    </div>
@endforeach
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change your `input` element to:

```
<input type="checkbox" value="{{ $role->name }}" {{ $user->hasRole($role->name) ? 'checked' : '' }}>
```

Checkboxes have a simple `checked` attribute, you don't assign a value to it.

[W3 Example](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_checked.asp)

Comment: Thanks for this! I am so sure I tried that first, but then in my annoyance I must have changed another part of the code that fixed the problem and then proceeded to break it again :)